# custom mapping table for base64

Tags: php, base64

i need to use base 64 to encrypt some data.
but while everyone can decode it, does it make sense to encode it?

so i need to use **custom maping table** to encode **insted of "ABCD......789+/"**

i found a function at php.net - 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php#78765

it can do what i need
but i don't know how to decode the encrypted data.

Comment: The idea of base64 encoding is not to encrypt data to prevent it from being read.  It's used to convert 8-bit data into 7-bit data for transmission.  In other words, it's used to convert binary data into text data so that it could be sent/received via mechanisms that can't deal with binary data.  For example, you can choose to base64 encoded image data to be sent inside XML.  If you want encryption that only you can decrypt, then base64 isn't the right choice.

Comment: Base64 is **NOT** encryption. In the encryption world, it's the equivalent of wrapping something in wet toilet paper. base64 is a mechanism to safe transport data through systems which may mangle the binary data.

Comment: whatever it is, how can i change it's mapping table?
i can use a base64 function in ASP with custom chars so i need to pass it to php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

base64 encryption really isn't for security. You want to use [mcrypt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) or similar for that. base64 is specifically for transferring data in a way that is safe and can be understood by multiple interested parties.

But, here is how you'd go about undoing that poster's method:

If you look at his comments, he's switched 's' and 9 (actually, his array has two 'S', but I think the second was a typo). So this should work:

```
// there is a more efficient way of doing this, but this was easy to demonstrate.
// you'll need to use temp stand-ins 
$res = str_replace( array( 9, 's' ), array( '{', '}' ), $input ); 
$res = str_replace( array( '{', '}' ), array( 's', 9 ), $res ); 
$base64_raw = '';

for( $i = 0; $i < strlen( $res ); $i++ )
{
    $tmp = $res[ $i ];
    // if it is upper case, then append the lower-case version.
    if( $tmp == strtoupper( $tmp ) ) $base64_raw .= strtolower( $tmp );
    // else append the upper-case version.
    else $base64_raw .= strtoupper( $tmp );
}

echo base64_decode( $base64_raw );
```